# A primitive permutation group with abelian point stabilizars

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Suppose that $G$ is a group acting primitively on a set $X$. Also suppose that all of its point stabilizers are abelian.

I want to prove that $G$ is either regular of prime degree or a Frobenius permutation group.

I have some ideas for proving this statement when $X$ is finite but in general, I don't have any useful ideas.

I will be so appreciate for any helpful answers and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not, then there exists $1 \ne g \in G$ that fixes more than one point. But for each $\alpha$ in the fixed point set of $g$, $C_G(g)$ contains the stabilizer $G_\alpha$, because $G_\alpha$ is abelian.

Since $G$ is primitive, we cannot have  $G_\alpha = G_\beta$ for $\alpha \ne \beta$ (I'll leave that for you to prove). So $C_G(g)$ strictly contains $G_\alpha$ and hence $C_G(g)$ is not maximal in $G$. But $G$ primitive is equivalent to the stabilizers being maximal.

This argument does not use finiteness of $G$.

Comment: Thank you so much because of your nice answer, but I don't understand one part completely. At the end of your argument, I unerstand that $G_\alpha <C_G(g) \leq G$ and $G_\alpha$ is maximal because $G$ is primitive. But why $C_G(g)=G$ cannot be happened?

Comment: Because $C_G(g)$ permutes the set of fixed points of $g$, so it cannot be transitive on $X$.

Comment: I got the point. Thank you so much.