# In a primitive group for different points the stabilizers are distinct

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions

If $G$ acts primitive on $\Omega$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \Omega$ are two distinct points, then $G_{\alpha} \ne G_{\beta}$.

It might be simple, but I do not see why it holds? I guess 
if $G_{\alpha} = G_{\beta}$, then $\Delta := \{\alpha,\beta\}$ is a candidate for block, of course we have $\alpha^x = \alpha \Leftrightarrow \beta^x = \beta$, but if $\alpha^x = \beta$, then I cannot establish $\beta^x = \alpha$ (I guess this must hold, at least it implies that $\Delta$ would be a block)?

Comment: Hint: $G_{\alpha}$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$, and if $\alpha^{y} = \beta$, then $G_{\beta} = y^{-1}G_{\alpha}y$, but $y \not \in G_{\alpha}$, since $\alpha \neq \beta$.

Comment: Sorry I do not see it, all I see is that this implies $y \notin G_{\beta}$, and that $G_{\beta}$ and $G_{\alpha}$ are conjugate does not implies that they must be different???

Comment: So (assuming that $G_\alpha = G_\beta$)$, y \in N_G(G_\alpha)$, so $G_\alpha < N_G(G_\alpha)$, but $G_\alpha$ is maximal, so $G_\alpha \unlhd G$, but then $G_\alpha$ fixes all points in $\Omega$, so $G$ is regular, so $G$ has prime order, but that's OK, so the question is wrong!!!

Comment: @DerekHolt: Okay, actually this is from an answer you gave where you wrote: "Since $G$ is primitive, we cannot have $G_{\alpha} = G_{\beta}$ for $\alpha\ne\beta$", now I am confused, can you please explain??? See here for your answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427333/a-primitive-permutation-group-with-abelian-point-stabilizars

Comment: If you look carefully at that answer, you will see that we were assuming that $G$ is not regular of prime degree.

Comment: Ah okay! But $\mbox{fix}(G_{\alpha})$ is a block for groups of finite degree (this is exercise 1.6.5 form Dixon & Mortimer, where they even state this in the errata, so it does not seem to be a faulty exercise). But if $fix(G_{\alpha})$ would be a block, then this implies my question, as if $G_{\alpha} = G_{\beta}$ then $\{\alpha,\beta\} \in \mbox{fix}(G_{\alpha})$, and $\mbox{fix}(G_{\alpha}) \ne \Omega$ as $G$ is not regular. Hence we have a non-trivial block, which gives $G_{\alpha}\ne G_{\beta}$ in the primitive case. Do you think the exercise is wrong???

Comment: You do need to include that $G$ is not regular in the question, otherwise it is wrong as stated.

Comment: Okay, but what about the statement that $\mbox{fix}(G_{\alpha})$ is a block (if $G$ acts transitive of finite degree). Is this also wrong???????? As it would imply my question????? But it is from an authoritive reference, and it is stated in the errata (with regard to another point), so I do not think it to be faulty???? Or do I have made a mistake in deriving that this would imply my question????

Comment: Well, (as Derek explained) in the case that $G$ is regular of prime degree, $G_{\alpha}$ is trivial for every $\alpha$, and then ${\rm fix }(G_{\alpha})$ is all of $\Omega$, (and is $G$-invariant), so there is no contradiction.

Comment: Yes. I see, thank you!